# Xbox Live Disconnection

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360, xbox-network

I turn on my Xbox 360, I sign in and it connects to Xbox Live. I try to boot a game up (in this case it's dark souls), and I get signed out of xbox live. Why is it doing this? I can't sign back in while the game is open, and if I try it will take forever to sign in, I waited 3 hours and it was still signing in. Please help!

Comment: Does it prompt you to update? Does your console have a hard drive?

Comment: i would recomment to change the title to something like "Xbox Live disconnect when starting a game" to clear up whats happening on the wirst look ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in the world of Xbox live and a simple "wipe" of your account should do the trick. After you've redownloaded your Account, the problem should be solved.

There is a [**thread in the Xbox-Forum**](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/8/t/121933.aspx) where people tried to collect several solutions. I hope this can help in your case.

### Here is a simple instruction:

> Step 1: Run the Live Connection Test
>
> Usually the test will go through as normal but just to be sure, check
>   the results in case there are any error codes or messages. In some
>   cases, running the test alone can sort things!
>
> Step 2: Clear the Console Cache
>
> Don’t worry if you’ve never done this before; clearing the cache on
>   the console won’t remove a Gamertag, DLC, game saves, or any dashboard
>   updates. It will clear out some temporary files and game “title
>   updates.” Those are the updates that get downloaded when a game starts
>   up.
>
> To clear the cache:
>
> Go to the Storage Menu
>
> Press ‘Y’ on a storage device (not the cloud)
>
> Select “Clear System Cache”
>
> Confirm with “Yes”
>
> That’s it! It only takes a second or two for the cache to clear. If
>   your Helpee thinks nothing happened, they may have just blinked and
>   missed it!
>
> Step 3: Re-download Profile
>
> Next, the helpee’s profile needs to be downloaded to the console
>   again. To avoid even the possibility of losing something important,
>   only recommend they download the profile. Do not recommend deleting
>   the profile! Downloading a profile is done by going to the Sign In or
>   Out Screen and going all the way to the right. Once the MSA and
>   password (or two-factor code) is entered, the download will start.
>
> Step 4: Restart the Console
>
> This is another safety step. Err on the side of caution and give the
>   console a little downtime.
>
> That should stabilize your helpee’s connection to Live! If any error
>   codes or other hurdles show up during these steps, switch gears and
>   work to resolve those before going on. Prepare to help with getting
>   passwords remembered and security proofs set!

Helpful links:

[**How to clear system cache**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/system/clear-system-cache)

[**How to delete/redownload/move etc. your profile**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/browse/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/Manage%20Profile)

The quoted instruction can be found [**here**](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/9/t/1831095.aspx).

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I have a question, when clearing chache, do I have to play a game all over again? How do I redownload my profile?

Comment: @JimJones See my answer step 2: `Don’t worry if you’ve never done this before; clearing the cache on the console won’t remove a Gamertag, DLC, game saves, or any dashboard updates` -> No removed saves. And see step 3 for redownloading your profile `Downloading a profile is done by going to the Sign In or Out Screen and going all the way to the right. Once the MSA and password (or two-factor code) is entered, the download will start.`

Comment: but will deleting chache also remove downloaded content too?